# hover fade in not executing

Tags: jquery

I'm decently knew to understanding the language that is jquery. I'm competent in HTML and CSS but this seems to be a higher learning curve than I have.

This is the code I plan to implement:
http://jsfiddle.net/yuQqh/15/

The fade in hover function isn't rendering and I'm not sure how to fix it.
Basically there are list items and the hovered list link should fade in to reveal the content of the list item's sub box, and then fade out when not hovered upon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put 'fast' is quotes in the fade commands. Also I don't recommend binding to mouseenter/mouseleave as you will have to setup a lot manually to make it behave smoothly. Is there a reason you are binding another mouseover to link1? anyway, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/yuQqh/20/

Comment: It was from a tutorial I was using but that works perfectly. Though I do have a quick follow up question. Sometimes for me the effects don't work until you wait for a couple seconds as if it needs to wait for the page or script to load, is that normal or could it just be something on my end?